# combinatorics : divide m objects into n boxes

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a question, I answer it but I don't know my answer is correct or not. My question is : 
Twelve teachers are to be assigned to three schools.  In how many ways can this be done if
i.  a specific school (School 1) receives at least 2 teachers? 
ii. each school receives exactly 4 teachers? 
My solution is :
i. if we get teachers and schools distinct objects and boxes respectively, we can divide 12 teachers into 3 schools in 3^{12} ways. We want the school 1 to have at least 2 teachers. The complement of it is that the school1 has 1 or 0 teacher. If the school1 has 0 teacher then we should divide 12 teachers into 2 schools so we have 2^12 ways. If the school1 has 1 teacher then we should choose 1 teacher of 12 and divide 11 teachers into 2 shools. So, in that case we have 12*2^11. Therefore the total ways are 3^12-(2^12+12*2^11).
ii. First we choose 4 of 12 then 4 of 8 and 4 of 4 finally. Hence, the total ways are 
485+70+1=556
Is my answer correct?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Your first solution is correct, but your second is not: in it you should be multiplying the numbers $\binom{12}4$, $\binom84$, and $\binom44$, since each of the $\binom{12}4$ possible sets of $4$ teachers in School $1$ can be combined with each of the $\binom84$ possible sets of teachers in School $2$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You’re very welcome.